# Explanation of a function that gets letter from word

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, substr

I'm making a hangman game in javascript, and I'm having trouble understanding the code in this one function.

Here is the function:

```
function getLetter(word,letter,display){
    // This method is called by the Hangman program when your isLetterInWord function
    // above returns true.
    // The parameters passed in are the guessed letter, the secret word,
    // and the current display state of the secret word.
    // This method will return a new display state of the secret word based on the matching letter.
    // REPLACE THIS CODE WITH YOUR getLetter() METHOD
    while (word.search(letter) != -1) {
        var index=word.search(letter)
        display = display.substr(0, index) + letter + display.substr(index + 1);        
        word = word.substr(0, index) + '-' + word.substr(index + 1);
    }
        return display;
}
```

The part I don't really understand:

```
display = display.substr(0, index) + letter + display.substr(index + 1);        
word = word.substr(0, index) + '-' + word.substr(index + 1);
```

Basically this program takes a word, find the number of letters and replaces them with hyphens. 
For example the word 'boat' would be turned to '----'

The the job of the function above is to replace the letter guess (correctly) with the corresponding hyphen.

Here is the background code for the whole project.

```
// Hangman Project
//RETURN A 'HIDDEN' VERSION OF THE SUPPLIED SECRET WORD
function getDisplay(word)
{   
    // Given a string, "word", return a hidden version of it consisting
    // of dashes for the display.
    // REPLACE THIS CODE WITH YOUR getDisplay() METHOD

    var disp="";
    for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++ ){
        disp = disp +'-';
    }
    return disp;
}

//FIND IF THE LETTER IS IN THE WORD
function isLetterInWord(word,letter){
    // Given the word "word", check if it contains the letter "letter".
    // REPLACE THIS CODE WITH YOUR isLetterInWord() METHOD

    if(word.search(letter) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Any help explaining those two lanes would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: MDN might be helpful, understanding [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) will help you to understand the whole code.

Comment: how can you have trouble understanding code you are making?

Comment: @dandavis obviously its not his, probably some hangman library he found on the net.

Comment: @Teemu I understand both of them. What I don't understand is at what point the hyphen is taken away. I see how the display adds the letter into the hyphens, but  I don't see when the extra hyphen is taken away.

Comment: Look at what `display.substr(0, index)` and `display.substr(index+1)` return. In particular, count how many characters there are in them, compared to the number of characters in the word.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the word is `animal`, and the player has already guessed `a` and `l` correctly. The input will be:

```
word = "animal"
letter = "i"
display = "a---al"
```

Follow the code:

```
var index = word.search(letter);
```

Now `index = 2` (counting is 0-based).

```
word = word.substr(0, index) + letter + word.substr(index+1);
```

`word.substr(0, 2)` is `"a-"`. `word.substr(3)` is `"-al"`. So when everything is concatenated `word = "a-i-al"`.

It's the `index+1` that skips over the character being replaced.

The next line

```
word = word.substr(0, index) + '-' + word.substr(index + 1);
```

is similar, replacing the found letter with `-`. This is needed in case the letter appears multiple times in the word (like `a` does in `animal`), so that the `while` loop won't keep trying to replace the same position.